# Postfix / Dovecot configure email for non-existing user

Tags: postfix, dovecot

My postfix / dovecot installation is already configured to accept mail for `me@A.com`. However, since my Apache is running multiple virtual domains with domain name mapping. I would like to create a `info@B.net` email that forwards to `me@A.com`. Is there a standard way to handle this?

Edit

Ok, I did as fkraiem said but this is what happened:

```
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 44: overriding earlier entry: virtual_alias_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
```

Below the `main.cf` file

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = A.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = A.com, localdomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_domains = B.net
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/transport
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
smtp-1000_destination_rate_delay = 12s
smtp-1000_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
smtp-1000_destination_recipient_limit = 2
smtp-1000_initial_destination_concurrency = 1
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.1/32 IP/32 [::1]/128 [::2]/128
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

And this error I got back after sending an email:

```
5.1.0 - Unknown address error 550-'5.1.1 <info@B.net>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table'
```

Comment: Yes, what you want is called virtual aliases, try to Google it.

Comment: Virtual aliases in postfix?

Comment: In Postfix, yes.

Comment: Actually, maybe not. How should mail sent to `me@B.net` or to `info@A.com` be handled? Should those addresses be rejected as nonexistent, or should all mail sent to `me@` (resp. `info@`) be handled in the same way?

Comment: Apache serves both domains, A.com and B.net. However, info@B.net shall be forwarded to me@A.com , or (you are right) could be forwarded to my real, private email address from a large provider. That eventually does not matter...

Comment: There are several ways to achieve that, but they differ in how they handle mail sent to other addresses, such as `me@B.net` or `info@A.com`. With the solution in my answer, both addresses will be rejected as invalid, but this may not be what you want

Comment: If you already have a `virtual_alias_maps` directive in your Postfix configuration, you must append `hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases` to it, not create a  new one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a mechanism in Posftix called [*virtual aliases*](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_alias) if

- your system handles mail for `domain.com` (*i.e.*, a MX record points to it); and
- you want to redirect all mail sent to `@domain.com` addresses to other, "real" addresses (no matter whether they're also hosted on your system or somewhere else such as on Gmail).

It's quite easy to do, there are mostly three steps.

1. Add the domain `domain.com` to the `virtual_alias_domains` directive in your Postfix configuration, and remove it from the `mydestination` directive if it is there.
2. Create the virtual aliases file for example at `/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases`. In it, put lines like this

   ```
   foo@domain.com real@address.com
   ```

   Mail sent to any address not explicitly mapped in the file will be rejected, but you can also add a catch-all address like this

   ```
   @domain.com catchall@address.com
   ```

   Then do `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_aliases` to create the hashed version of the file, which Postfix will actually use.
3. Add `hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases` to the `virtual_alias_maps` directive in your Postfix configuration.

And after reloading Postfix it should do what you want.

Comment: When I do this ALL mail goes to the catch-all address, not just mail sent to non-existent accounts. This seems to be a very common problem.

Comment: @CaptainForkbeard It does not do that here. Do you see anything in `mail.log` or `mail.err`?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary and it is normal behaviour. From http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_alias: "...shows how one would implement a catch-all virtual alias that receives mail for every example.com address not listed in the virtual alias file." So if you're using a database for storing e-mail addresses this will not work (unless you list all addresses in the virtual_aliases file as well).